# threading programming in python

Tags: python, flask

Recently I've been practicing to build a website with flask. Now i encounter a problem.
There is a function which to achieve registration. The code like this:

```
    def register():
        ...
        some judgment
        ...
        if true:
        sendmail()
        return redirect(url_for('onepage'))
```

My question is :
When preforming sendmail(), it needs much time. So the users have to wait for a moment to get "onepage", about 4-5s. This will bring a bad experience.   I know that using threading can let these two functions independently of each other, but I have learnt programming for a very short time so I have no experience in threading programming, Could anybody provide some ideas or code examples for me at this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html) rather than the low-level [`thread`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/_thread.html) (which has been renamed to `_thread` in Python 3). For a case this simple, there will be no need of subclassing `threading.Thread`, so you could just replace `sendmail()` by:

```py
threading.Thread(target=sendmail).start()
```

after:

```py
import threading
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of implementing threading in Python.
One very simple solution for you would be

```
    import thread
    def register():
        ...
        some judgment
        ...
        if true:
        thread.start_new_thread(sendmail,())
        return redirect(url_for('onepage'))
```

This will start `sendmail()` asynchronously. However, if `sendmail` fails or returns something, you will need to use something else.

There are plenty of tutorials about Threading in python, I found this quite nice http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Thanks elactic! It's really useful for me !

Comment: You're, welcome. But Evpok is right, `threading` might be the better choice over `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

I have not threading solution: I'm using celery for hard operations: send email, fetch url, create many database records, periodic tasks.

**+** you can use flask application and celery instances on different servers

**-** you need backend (rabbitmq, redis, mongodb and etc.)

Comment: ok. Thanks tbicr. I'll take a look at flask-celery. Hoping it can help me. Thanks~

Comment: From celery 3.0 you can use just `celery` without `flask-celery`.